# Troubleshooting JSON Mapping for POST Request with an object and string params

Tags: c#, json, .net, rest, post

Description:

I'm encountering a challenge with formatting the JSON body for a POST request to an API endpoint in my ASP.NET Core application. I hope to seek guidance and find a solution to this issue.

API Signature:

```
[HttpPost("CreateProjectUser")] 
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProjectUserAsync(HikariUser projectUser, string userName)
```

JSON Body (inputData):

```json
{
    "projectUser": {
        "Username": "exampleProjectUser",
        "Email": "exampleProjectUser1@example.com",
        "Password": "Abc!123",
        "Role": "Contributor"
    },
    "userName": "AM" 
}
```

Issue Description:

The problem I'm facing is that the "userName" property in the JSON payload is being incorrectly mapped to HikariUser projectUser.UserName when it should actually fill the exampleProjectUser field. Furthermore, the other properties of the HikariUser object are not being correctly populated and are appearing as null.

Additional Information:

Here is the HikariUser class with [JsonPropertyName] attributes:

```cs
[JsonObject("projectUser")]
public class HikariUser
{
    [JsonPropertyName("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

What I've Tried:

I have already attempted to use [JsonPropertyName("")] attributes to control the JSON property names, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Seeking Guidance:

I'm seeking guidance and potential solutions to ensure the correct mapping of JSON properties to the method parameters of my API endpoint. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: One thing to note is that you are mixing attributes from System.Text.Json and Json.NET. [`[JsonPropertyName]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0) is from System.Text.Json while [`[JsonObject]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonobjectattribute.htm) is from Newtonsoft.Json.  Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create one more class

```
public class User
{
public HikariUser projectUser {get; set;}
public string userName {get; set;}
}
```

and fix the action header

```
public async Task CreateProjectUserAsync([FromBody] User user)
```